# Python: pd.read_csv - import all numbers after the decimal

Tags: python, csv

In my csv file that I wish to import, I have a column `Timestamp` with nanoseconds precision:
34200.154875632 and so on.

When I write:

```
dfr = pd.read_csv(files,index_col=None,usecols=['Timestamp','Price'], header=0,dtype=np.float)  
df=DataFrame(dfr)
```

I do not get a `DataFrame` with a column of `Timestamp` with all nice decimals...only six. I tried to play around with the input `dtype=np.float` but no result. What's the missing argument in `pd.read_csv` to have all nine decimals?

Comment: Are you also using Numpy?

Comment: Yes I am also using numpy

Comment: Your data does have the full precision, it's just truncating the _displayed representation_ of the data to 6 decimals.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the correct code

```
import Pandas
pd.options.display.float_format = '{:20,.2f}'.format
```

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to the print precision of pandas. Look into pandas.set_printoptions.

It looks like pandas.set_printoptions is now deprecated in v0.13, it seems to use pandas.set_option

Comment: Because this is a `pandas.DataFrame`, the OP will need to use `pandas.set_printoptions` instead.

Comment: These are my set_options:

`pd.set_option('display.height', 1000)
pd.set_option('display.max_rows', 5000)
pd.set_option('display.max_columns', 30)
pd.set_option('display.width', 1000)`

and it does not change to the print with 6 decimals. I will have to look at this into more details

Comment: I don't have 0.13 installed at the moment, I would dig through all the options and there is probably one for precision